# Trouble searching combined ranges in HLOOKUP

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

[image: Example from Sheets]

I'm having trouble with `HLOOKUP` in Google Sheets. I'm trying to determine whether an inputted word is unique in a row and for this reason my formula searches combined ranges [that exclude itself] within an `HLOOKUP`. This is the formula I'm using [in cell E4]:

```
=HLOOKUP(E2, {B2:D3;F2:M3}, 2, false)
```

Doubtless, there's something I'm doing wrong, because I keep getting this error:

> "HLOOKUP evaluates to an out-of-bounds range"

What I want to happen is that it will find a match for "ice" in the range to the left [B2:D3] and the range to the right [F2:M3]...

Confusingly, the equivalent formula works for `VLOOKUP`, but not `HLOOKUP`. I've found it also works in `HLOOKUP` if I search for a single range [ie B2:D3] and not a combined range.

So I'm a bit stuck. The combined range search works fine in `VLOOKUP`, but perhaps I need to write it differently for `HLOOKUP`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure. Sorry it's so incredibly messy. I'm new to Google sheets ;) 
[deleted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this:

```
=HLOOKUP(E2, {B2:D3; F2:M3}, 2, 0)
```

try this:

```
=HLOOKUP(E2, {B2:D3, F2:M3}, 2, 0)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks so much you're a freaking genius. Not sure why the syntax is different for HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP, but it's working perfectly when I use a comma [,] instead of semicolon [;] to separate combined ranges...hope this helps someone in the future :)

Comment: it has to do with arranging the ranges in array brackets `{}`

Comment: Ah ok. I have no idea what that means! ;) Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: paste this in some cell `={"a","b"}` and also `={"a";"b"}` and see the difference

Answer (score 0):

For *identifying* duplicates conditional formatting might suit you. Select all relevant columns : Format > Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... *Custom formula is* and:

```
=countif(1:1,A1)>1
```

with formatting of your choice.

This should format all instances of any value repeated in its row.

Comment: Ok awesome I'll try that too. I'm really looking to identify text (or would your answer work for that as well as numbers?). Thanks heaps for your kind suggestion